# Understanding how delegate is going to get trigger in a code

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, react-native

I was going through Jitsi Meet code and they have created a [delegate](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/ios/sdk/src/JitsiMeetViewDelegate.h) for their UIView

[Their Delegate class](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/ios/sdk/src/JitsiMeetViewDelegate.h)

[JitsiMeetView Where they are using it](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/ios/sdk/src/JitsiMeetView.h#L34)

Consider they have this delegate

```
- (void)audioMutedChanged:(NSDictionary *)data;
```

Which they have implemented in [view controller](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/ios/sdk/src/JitsiMeetView.h#L34)

```
- (void)audioMutedChanged:(NSDictionary *)data {
  NSLog(@"%@%@", @"Audio muted changed: ", data[@"muted"]);
}
```

I am unable to figure out how will `audioMutedChanged` gets called

Can someone please help me in understanding their code?

Comment: It's in their SDK that the method is called.  Somewhere, there might be something when it detect the muting: `if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(audioMuteDidChanged:)]) { [delegate audioMutedChanged:someDictionary];}`. It's hidden code, the same way your `UITableViewDelegate` methods are called for instance, or any other delegate.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the implementation inside `JitsiMeetView.m`, it has following method.

```
- (void)setAudioMuted:(BOOL)muted {
    ExternalAPI *externalAPI = [[JitsiMeet sharedInstance] getExternalAPI];
    [externalAPI sendSetAudioMuted:muted];
}
```

If you take a look at the implementation inside `ExternalAPI.m`, you will see this.

```
- (void)sendSetAudioMuted:(BOOL)muted {
    NSDictionary *data = @{ @"muted": [NSNumber numberWithBool:muted]};

    [self sendEventWithName:setAudioMutedAction body:data];
}
```

And this is the final place your delegate callback is invoked from.

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(sendEvent:(NSString *)name
                       data:(NSDictionary *)data
                      scope:(NSString *)scope) {
    // The JavaScript App needs to provide uniquely identifying information to
    // the native ExternalAPI module so that the latter may match the former
    // to the native JitsiMeetView which hosts it.
    JitsiMeetView *view = [JitsiMeetView viewForExternalAPIScope:scope];

    if (!view) {
        return;
    }

    id delegate = view.delegate;

    if (!delegate) {
        return;
    }
    
    if ([name isEqual: @"PARTICIPANTS_INFO_RETRIEVED"]) {
        [self onParticipantsInfoRetrieved: data];
        return;
    }

    SEL sel = NSSelectorFromString([self methodNameFromEventName:name]);

    if (sel && [delegate respondsToSelector:sel]) {
        [delegate performSelector:sel withObject:data];
    }
}
```